# spring data couchbase save entity does not return id

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I'm working on a spring webflux project with couchbase.
The problem is when I want to save an entity, the returned entity does not contain its ID auto generated.
And I need its ID in order to update it after if I want to, or delete it for example.

So I would like to know if there is a way to get the auto generated ID?

This is my entity class :

```
@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = UNIQUE)
   private String id;
   @Field
   private String name;
   @NonNull
   @Field
   private String firstname;

}
```

Also I use the ReactiveCouchbaseRepository.

This is my repository :

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "person")
public interface PersonRepository extends 
ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Person, String> {
    Flux<Person> findAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the entity class and how you try to save it into DB?

Comment: I've just added.

Comment: call saveAndFlush() method or just flush()

Comment: There is no such method on the couchbase repository.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to reproduce your bug I found out using `ReactiveCouchbaseRepository` the entity id is not set as it should be.

For `CouchbaseRepository` it's not the case, the entity is populated with the generated id.

There is an open bug describing this problem: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH-383

Comment: Thank you for the link of the bug. It seems that it will not be resolved soon as the priority is minor...

Comment: How do we get document ID after save? Is there any workaround?

Comment: @paralen I generated the UUID myself instead of using the auto generation from couchbase.